# The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests

Tags: c#, node.js, npm

I faced with this problem:

[image]

The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: 'rimraf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

```
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! CallerPanelProject@0.1.0 start: `rimraf ./build && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the CallerPanelProject@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

))
TSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
```

Comment: Put code into codeblocks. Put the output into the psot as text, not images. Also what exaqctly does this have to do with C# and JavaScript?

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem when made the Node SPA app inside ASP .NET Core and tried to perform `start` node app in the Production mode. In Development mode everything was OK.
This line in `Stratup.cs` file caused the problem:

```
spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
```

a source of the problem is: in the production mode Node app has been bundled already, i.e. it has no *package.json* and other Node related files, so `start` request is not possible to do.

A good way to fix that is to put `start` in to the clause:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

Comment: I came up with a similar idea myself, although I found that the IsDevelopment check was too coarse for when you want a stack dump on the deployed system: https://www.pmichaels.net/2020/07/04/debugging-an-asp-net-core-react-application-in-azure/

Comment: This piece of code is already include in .NET 5.0 in the startup class. Thus didn´t work.

Comment: @PaulMichaels should be the accepted answer (at least for .net 5)

Answer (score 8):

You might have missed installing the dependencies in your source project. That is why it is unable to start to run your application without references.

Run `npm install` in your source project would resolve the issue

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem, after starting afresh with Visual Studio 2019 after a longer break from it (so prette clean setup). It happened when I just tried to set up the simplest ASP.NET Core app, these are the steps I followed / roughly:

- Check logs in "Event Viewer" for your app - there I found 
  "Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
  It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
  The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found."
- Went into Visual Studio Installer (Visual Studio | Tools | Get Tools and Features).
- Select the "Individual Components" tab.
- Check all (applicable) modules under .NET for ".NET Core .."-anything (I took them all).
- Hit "Install while loading"
- Restart Visual Studio.
- Voila: ASP.NET core app started without errors.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I needed to specifically install .net core 3.0 runtime on my pc. I only had 3.1 and 2 and lower installed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by running "npm install rimraf" in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

A similar error as @JamesPoulose but I had installed npm. The problem was I installed it when Visual Studio was open. Event Viewer therefore showed me this error:

> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices
>
> EventId: 0
>
> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

[image]

A simple restart of Visual Studio fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a very silly problem. After re-installing my Windows, I missed installing `npm` altogether and then running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague, Dave Wilson, fixed this for me. Went to our react project folder and deleted the node_modules. Next went to the command prompt and **npm i** in the project folder. Checked the output of npm i and saw that Python was not installed when the module fibres has a dependency on it. Installed python and added it to PATH  in system variables. The key thing is to check the output of npm i.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when Selecting HTTPS instead of HTTP. When running it on your localhost. Inside your visual studio project: Properties/launchSettings.json, change "applicationULR" to route to http instead of https(see image)

[settings change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHsha.png)