# ASP.NET Core with React error - The npm script 'start' exited

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, create-react-app

I am creating a new asp.net core project in VS 2019. It's a web app in core v5 with React. I have NodeJS v14 installed. When I run the project once I create it, I get this error:

> The npm script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests

I haven't changed any line of code and this is the result of the scaffolding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883331/the-npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-the-create-react-app-serve)

Comment: No. The new project scaffolding already has that if condition in place and it's still not working. Plus, it's running in development for me and not working.

Comment: have you try "npm start" in cmd?

Comment: Does it show the error output?

Comment: @NormanW - Gonzalo's answer seems to be correct.  Worked for me after struggling for weeks with this

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably your "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" variable in Development enviroment. If you look your Startup.cs file, you will find this lines:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

When you upload that code to a server with the developmen variable, the angular CLI cannot be launched a second time, so it crashes and gives that error message. You can substitute it for:

```
 #if DEBUG
    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
 #endif
```

I recommend this second option, since if you use the first one, the application will stop working locally.