# Error when opening a MS Teams Personal App in Mozilla, Edge or Opera browser

Tags: microsoft-teams, msteams-react-base-component

I have created a MS Teams personal app, everything was working fine till few days ago. But then I started receiving this error in Mozilla, Edge and Opera browser.

This is working as expected in Chrome browser.

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: ))

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was:

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might have missed installing the dependencies in your source project. That is why it is unable to start to run your application without references. Could you please navigate to your react project folder and delete the node_modules ? Next go to the command prompt and Run npm install in your source project folder.

Comment: Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883331/the-npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-the-create-react-app-serve) thread which discusses similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Prasad, the mozilla is still showing the error. even after clearing the cache and closing the browser for the multiple times. Edge and chrome is working now. Any idea?

Comment: When I checked in colleagues device he is facing the issue in chrome and edge as well , so weird thing is happening

Comment: We also checked by setting the personal app and it is working fine in all browsers for us.